# Use of substring in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

My query is the following:

```
SELECT id, category FROM table1
```

This returns the following rows:

```
ID|category
1 |{IN, SP}
2 | 
3 |{VO}
```

Does anyone know how i can remove the first char and last char of the string in PostgreSQL, so it removes: {}?

Comment: Can these two characters show up somewhere else? (And supposed to be kept?)

Comment: No. I want to retrieve the String in my select statement without {} but it's a foreign column containing an array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure, what you mean with "*foreign column*", but as the column is an array, the best way to deal with that is to use `array_to_string()`

```
SELECT id, array_to_string(category, ',') as category
FROM table1;
```

The curly braces are not part of the stored value. This is just the [string representation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-IO) of an array that is used to *display* it.

Answer (score 2):

Either using multiple `REPLACE` functions.

```
SELECT id, REPLACE(REPLACE(category, '{', ''), '}', '') 
FROM table1
```

Or using a combination of the `SUBSTRING`, `LEFT` & `LENGTH` functions

```
SELECT id, LEFT(SUBSTRING(category, 2, 999),LENGTH(SUBSTRING(category, 2, 999)) - 1)
FROM table1
```

Or just `SUBSTRING` and `LENGTH`

```
SELECT id, SUBSTRING(category, 2, LENGTH(category)-2)
FROM table1
```

Comment: `len()` is not a PostgreSQL function (neither is an ANSI SQL one). You could use `length()`, `char_length()` or `character_length()`

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the `{}` with an empty string

```
SELECT id, replace(replace(category, '{', ''), '}', '') FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,
      substring(category,charindex('{',category,len(category))+2,len(category)-2) 
from table1;
```

Comment: There is no `charindex()` or `len()` function in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id
      ,left(right(category,length(category)-1),length(category)-2) category 
from boo
```

---

```
select id
       ,trim(both '{}' from category) 
from boo
```

[`Trim()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-string.html):

> Remove the longest string containing only the characters (a space by
>   default) from the start/end/both ends of the string

Answer (score -1):

**The syntax for the replace function in PostgreSQL is:**

**replace( string, from_substring, to_substring )**

**Parameters or Arguments**

**string**
The source string.

**from_substring**
The substring to find. All occurrences of from_substring found within string are replaced with to_substring.
**to_substring**
The replacement substring. All occurrences of from_substring found within string are replaced with to_substring.

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE dbo.table1
SET category = REPLACE(category, '{', '')
WHERE ID <=3

UPDATE dbo.table1
SET category = REPLACE(category, '}', '')
WHERE ID <=3
```